# using the keyword 'struct' to declare struct objects and in malloc

Tags: c, struct

I'm currently reading a book on algorithms programmed in C and I noticed that when the author is going to declare/create a struct object he does this (the structs have already been defined by the way):

```
struct hashTable * h;
```

And this:

```
struct hashTableNode ** table;
```

And even when calling malloc he does this:

```
h = malloc(sizeof(struct hashTable));
```

So when I was programming the code, I tried it without using the word 'struct' in the above declarations to see if it still worked since the structs were already defined. And sure enough they did work. So my question is why is 'struct' needed in these declarations, as it just makes lines of code longer. Is it absolutely necessary or not? Or is it just some 'safe' technique that makes the code more compatible?

Comment: Are you using a real C compiler, or are you actually using a C++ compiler?

Comment: I'm using visual studio, so I guess c++?

Comment: If you want to learn actual C I suggest using a C compiler. The way you refer to structs is different in C and C++ - although some people tend to always typedef their structs in C so they don't have to keep typing `struct`, i.e. the `typedef struct` idiom.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen I'm new to C so I'm not sure what you mean by "typedef their structs"

Comment: @Ghost_Stark then leave it for later and first make sure to use a C compiler as Matti said (or, in visual studio, make sure your *file* is named `.c` and not `.cpp` -- there's an option in project settings forcing to compile in C mode, too.

Comment: @Ghost_Stark if you want to learn "modern" C, visual studio is a bad choice, the compiler only supports the oldest standard (C89)

Comment: @FelixPalmen I actually do have to use the C compiler in linux (gcc) but I'm using visual studio because the program I'm coding is pretty big and visual studio has a very good debugging program. I'm not familiar with other debugging ones so I stuck with visual studio's.

Comment: @Ghost_Stark chances are a program written with `gcc` uses some newer standard (C99 or C11) and won't work with visual studio's compiler anyways. For windows, get e.g. "mingw" and learn the usage of `gdb`, it's a great debugger.

Comment: @FelixPalmen ok thanks. I'll look into mingw!

Comment: If you absolutely want visual studio, try integrating with `mingw`, just found this on google: http://visualgdb.com/tutorials/mingw/

Comment: @FelixPalmen Every time I hear someone say gdb is a great debugger, I have to wonder if they've ever used a debugger GUI. (although I'm sure there are GUI front-ends for gdb)

Comment: @immibis you may stop wondering, the answer is yes.

Comment: @immibis indeed, the answer für me is *every single work day* (for CLR code with Visual Studio). Still `gdb` is great, you actually can use it with IDEs (there are plugins for lots of them) and the default CLI gives you access to all it's features for full flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on if there's a `typedef` to give this struct an alias. When you found out that the same code works without the `struct` keyword, it's probably calling the alias of your struct.

More specifically, when there is no `typedef`, you have to give the compiler a hint that your personal name `hashTable` is a struct, like this:

```
struct hashTable{
    int a, b;
};

int main ()
{
    struct hashTable t1;
}
```

People often use `typedef` to give the struct an alias though. In this case, the compiler already knows that the alias is actually your previously defined struct, so you don't need a `struct` keyword anymore. The following code would work as well:

```
typedef struct hashTable{
    int a, b;
}apple;

int main ()
{
    apple t1;
}
```

Lastly, you must find out that why don't we just give the struct its name as its alias? So, the following code would probably work best:

```
typedef struct hashTable{
    int a, b;
}hashTable;

int main ()
{
    struct hashTable t1;
    hastTable t2;
}
```

**Update:** 
In C++, you actually CAN create a `struct`, and declare instances just use the name of your struct. For example:

```
struct hashTable{
    int a, b;
};

int main ()
{
   hashTable t1;
}
```